# How do I get a div to stretch from to the div above to the div below it?

Tags: css, html

Here is what I'm working [with](http://jsfiddle.net/c8nc7rcx/1/)

Code:

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px !important;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: pink;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  header
</header>
<div class="content">
  content-main
  <br />

</div>
<footer>
  footer
</footer>
```

I want the pink bit to stretch to the top and bottom. I don't really care if the scroll bar is for the pink content div or the body div. I just need my it to fill up the whole page and scroll when It overflows.

One additional constraint I have is that I would like the pink content to still fill all the empty space if the footer is dynamically removed.

Answer (score 4):

> One additional constraint I have is that I would like the pink content
>   to still fill all the empty space if the footer is dynamically removed.

Use `flexbox` for that,

Adding a new element to wrap the others, you can set the wrap as `display:flex; flex-direction:column` and give `flex:1` to the `.content`.

**Note:** you will need `height:100%` in `html,body` and in the wrapper element, in order to `flex:1` work in this case.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%
}
header,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
}
header {
  top: 0;
  height: 60px
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <header>
    header
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    content-main
  </div>
  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `%`, use `vh` to set your container min-height to take up the full page

```
.content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: pink;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 90px); /* 100% the height of the screen minus header and footer */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Digedu/5n1azfyn/

Comment: Scrap my answer, go with @dippas

Answer (score 0):

Use this setting for `.content`:

min-height: calc(100vh - 90px);

(That's the full window height minus the heights of header and footer)

Comment: Use vh or set the body to 100% height